# How to get Vertex Color data from multiple objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors, custom-attributes

Using Geometry Nodes, is it possible to get the Vertex Colors of two separate objects with the same topology, and mix them?

I know mixing of colors can (obviously) be done in the material, but I am thinking of linking Vertex Color change to a mesh deformation that occurs inside GN.

I also realize that getting Vertex Color data into GN is simple when the data exists *on the same object the GN modifier is on*. (Just plug in an input socket and specify the `Col` attribute in the modifier.)

But getting Vertex Color data from *another* object, I'm not so sure about. The **Object Info** node doesn't have an output socket for this. Maybe the attribute can be captured from the `Geometry` output socket's data, but I haven't had any luck with that so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Blender 3.2* you can get this value via `Named Attribute`.

This node gives you the vertex color of the selected geometry.

[image]

If you then process this accordingly and store it in your target geometry with the node `Store Named Attribute`, you can use it in the shader.

However, you can only access them directly in the shader via `Color Attribute` if you have previously created an attribute with the name "Col" in the geometry that contains the *Geometry Nodes*.

Otherwise you would have to query this attribute in the shader with the node `Attribute`.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you! :-) I noticed the **Store Named Attribute** node in your example uses `Vector` instead of `Color`. Is that simply because in effect they are the same in this example? Also, my **Transfer Attribute** nodes have a drop-down selector for `Color`, `Vector`, etc., but I noticed yours do not - although we are both using Blender 3.2... any idea what's going on there? (At first I thought yours were *hidden*, but it's not that.)

Comment: @Mentalist Oh, sorry about that, it's a bad habit of mine to save space: If the node options are self-explanatory or on default settings, I usually hide them with *Toggle Node Options*. And yes, here in this example it doesn't really matter if *Vector* or *Color* is selected, but I fixed it so there's less misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's in the **Node** menu. I had no idea... learned something new. Thank you for clarifying.